# PBR does not work on incoming interface, but works on outgoing subinterface

Tags: gns3, pbr

This lab is on Dynamips. 
[image: 6 routers topology]
I have a PBR configured on R6 which lets a packet from SW1 lo0 heading to the even ones of R1 lo1 go through R4 and a packet from SW1 lo0 heading to the odd ones through R5.

The thing is that the route-map doesn't work when it's configured on e1/0, and it works when it's configured on e1/0.46. Which doesn't make sense to me since e1/0.46 is not the interface into which the target packet is coming.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

The configuration is as follows:

```
int e1/0
no shut
du full
ip add 1.1.67.6 255.255.255.240
ip policy route-map PBR
!
int e1/0.46
en dot1q 46
ip add 1.1.46.6 255.255.255.240
ip ospf message-digest-key 55 md5 cisco55
!
int e1/1
no shut
du full
ip add 1.1.56.6 255.255.255.240
ip ospf message-digest-key 55 md5 cisco55
!
route-map PBR permit 100
match ip add 100
set ip next-hop 1.1.46.4
!
route-map PBR permit 200
match ip add 110
set ip next-hop 1.1.56.5
!
access-list 100 permit ip 7.7.7.0 0.0.0.255 172.16.0.0 0.0.6.255
!
access-list 110 permit ip 7.7.7.0 0.0.0.255 172.16.1.0 0.0.6.255
!
!vlan 46 network: 1.1.46.0/28
!vlan 56 network: 1.1.56.0/28
!SW1 Lo0: 7.7.7.7/24
```

Routing table in R6 is as follows:

```
R6#sh ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 8 subnets, 3 masks
O E1    1.1.1.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/1
                [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    1.1.12.0/30 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                    [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    1.1.23.0/30 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                    [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
C       1.1.46.0/28 is directly connected, Ethernet1/0.46
C       1.1.56.0/28 is directly connected, Ethernet1/1
C       1.1.67.0/28 is directly connected, Ethernet1/0
O IA    1.1.78.0/28 [110/11] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:02, Ethernet1/0
O E1    1.1.100.0/29 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                     [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
     2.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O E1    2.2.2.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/1
                [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/0.46
     3.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O E1    3.3.3.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/1
                [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/0.46
     4.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       4.4.4.0 [110/11] via 1.1.46.4, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0.46
     5.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       5.5.5.0 [110/11] via 1.1.56.5, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/1
     6.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       6.6.6.0 is directly connected, Loopback0
     172.16.0.0/24 is subnetted, 15 subnets
O IA    172.16.12.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.13.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.14.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.15.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.8.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.9.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:01, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.10.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:02, Ethernet1/0
O IA    172.16.11.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:02, Ethernet1/0
O E1    172.16.4.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    172.16.5.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    172.16.6.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:51, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    172.16.7.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    172.16.1.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    172.16.2.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
O E1    172.16.3.0 [110/30] via 1.1.56.5, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/1
                   [110/30] via 1.1.46.4, 00:00:52, Ethernet1/0.46
     7.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O       7.7.7.0 [110/11] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:23, Ethernet1/0
     8.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
O IA    8.8.8.0 [110/12] via 1.1.67.7, 00:01:02, Ethernet1/0
```

Its physical map could be drawn like the following:
[image: physical map]

Comment: I don't see the config for E1/1.  Can you also post he output of "show ip route"?

Comment: @RonTrunk, thanks for your interest. I just added the e1/1 config and R6 routing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your connections between R4, R6 and SW1 are wrong, causing the issue:

> R4 (**interface e1/1**) is connecting to R6 (**subinterface
>   e1/0.46**), while R6 (**interface e1/0**) is connecting to SW1 ? <= This is nonsense.

When using sub-interfaces, you should avoid any configuration on main interface.

Connections/configuration between R4, R6 and SW1 should be as clear as the connection between R5 and R6.

Comment: Ah, that's because the map isn't a physical map. I drew L3 devices only. So R6 is physically connected to SW1 and through SW1 & SW2 it's also connected to R4.

Comment: @saba As I mentioned earlier, `When using sub-interfaces, you should avoid any configuration on its main interface.` With your new physical diagram, you should use one main interface/port on R6 to connect SW1. The other interface/port on R6, you configure it with TWO sub-interfaces to connect R4 and R5.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but this is a lab. So I'm supposed to work with it as it's designed. I wasn't asking for a way to change the map. I was asking why the PBR isn't working as it should.

Comment: @Saba it is because the configuration on both main and sub-interfaces caused abnormal behavior. `When using sub-interfaces, you should avoid any configuration on its main interface`.

Comment: I don't understand what your point is. I asked a question because I clearly did not understand what is happening. And all you're telling me is that I set it up wrong and I didn't understand right. In your statements, there's no explanation of why, except repeating that the main interface shouldn't be used when the sub-interfaces are used. I got that part.

Comment: @Saba I did not mean any offense. As I explained early `it is because the configuration on both main and sub-interfaces caused abnormal behavior`. The physical main/parent interface in this case is used to move the traffic only, thus we should not put any specific configuration (here is PBR) on it as it would not work properly (at all).

Comment: I guess your answer is as much as I can get, and I should avoid putting any configuration on the main interface when it has sub-interface configured. But it's kind of strange to me that they let us change the native vlan.

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited to a comment, but my reputation doesn't allow me to do that. So here goes:

I am confused with your physical diagram and your logical representation. According to the physical diagram , if R6 connects to SW1 on E1/0, then fa1/6 on the switch should be configured as a trunk. Which means, you should have two sub-interfaces e1/0.67 and e1/0.46 on R6 to cater to the different VLANs. If I understood this incorrectly, then my apologies. Also Hung Tran is right. If you have subinterfaces, then configuring on the main interface is not optimal.

From routing perspective, you should check 2 things:

1. If the switch is capable of performing routing, is there a default route or a static route for R1's loopbacks pointing to e1/0's IP address.
2. If the switch does not support routing, then make sure the default gateway is set to e1/0's IP. If the switch is CISCO's then the command is "ip default-gateway "

Comment: Because this was done on Dynamips, there are only 6 routers & 2 switches in play and their connections are already set. Which means there aren't a lot of room for moving around interface connections. So we had a lot of trunk configurations, and since we can use the main interface by changing the native VLAN, we did so.

If I may, why is it not optimal to configure on the main interface when there're subinterfaces? And if it's just a better way, shouldn't it work anyway though it's not optimal? (By the way, the switch is L3 switch.)